# Angular app not updating is frontend though working fine in database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, crud

I'm trying to make a Crud app in angular, but while adding the data(requirements) through an form its is getting updated in the database, but not displaying in frontend(table in my case is not created)

**add-requirement-component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Requirement } from '../requirement';
import { RequirementService } from '../requirement.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-requirement',
  templateUrl: './add-requirement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-requirement.component.css']
})
export class AddRequirementComponent implements OnInit {
  requirement: Requirement = new Requirement();

  constructor(private requirementService: RequirementService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  saveRequirement(){
    this.requirementService.addRequirement(this.requirement).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.goToRequirementList();
    },
    error => console.log(error));
  }

  goToRequirementList(){
    this.router.navigate(['/requirements'])

  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.requirement);
    this.saveRequirement();
  }

}
```

**add-requirement.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AddOfferComponent } from './add-offer.component';

describe('AddOfferComponent', () => {
  let component: AddOfferComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddOfferComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AddOfferComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddOfferComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**add-requirement.component.html**

```
<div class ="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
<h2> Add Requirement</h2>
<form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Title </label>
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" id = "title"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.title" name = "title">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Description </label>
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" id = "description"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.description" name = "description">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Category </label>
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" id = "category"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.category" name = "category">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Type </label>
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" id = "type"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.type" name = "type">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Price </label>
        <input type= "number" class = "form-control" id = "price"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.price" name = "price">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Employee Id </label>
        <input type= "number" class = "form-control" id = "empId"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.empId" name = "empId">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Is Available </label>
        <input type= "text" class = "form-control" id = "isAvailable"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.isAvailable" name = "isAvailable">
    </div> <br>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label> Available Upto </label>
        <input type= "date" class = "form-control" id = "availableUpto"
            [(ngModel)] = "requirement.availableUpto" name = "availableUpto">
    </div> <br>

    <button class = "btn btn-success" type="submit"> Add </button>
</form>
</div>
```

**Here comes the another component**
**requirement-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Requirement } from '../requirement';
import { RequirementService } from '../requirement.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-requirement-list',
  templateUrl: './requirement-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./requirement-list.component.css']
})
export class  RequirementListComponent implements OnInit {

  requirements:  Requirement[];

  constructor(private  requirementService:  RequirementService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRequirements();
  }

  private getRequirements(){
    this.requirementService.getRequirementList().subscribe(data => {
      this.requirements = data;
    })
  }

  updateRequirement(resId: number){
    this.router.navigate(['update-requirement', resId]);
  }

}
```

**requirement-list.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RequirementListComponent } from './requirement-list.component';

describe('RequirementListComponent', () => {
  let component: RequirementListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RequirementListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RequirementListComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RequirementListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**requiremnt-list.component.html**

```
<h2>Requirement List</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Resource Id</th>
            <th> Category</th>
            <th> Type</th>
            <th> Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let requirement of requirements">
            <td>{{ requirement.resId}}</td>
            <td>{{ requirement.category}}</td>
            <td>{{ requirement.type}}</td>
            <td>
                <button (click) = "updateRequirement(requirement.resId)" class = "btn btn-info"> Update</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddRequirementComponent } from './add-requirement/add-requirement.component';
import { RequirementListComponent } from './requirement-list/requirement-list.component';
import { UpdateRequirementComponent } from './update-requirement/update-requirement.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'requirements', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'requirements', component: RequirementListComponent},
  {path: 'add-requirement', component: AddRequirementComponent},
  {path: 'update-requirement/:resId', component: UpdateRequirementComponent}
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RequirementListComponent } from './requirement-list/requirement-list.component';
import { AddRequirementComponent } from './add-requirement/add-requirement.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UpdateRequirementComponent } from './update-requirement/update-requirement.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RequirementListComponent,
    AddRequirementComponent,
    UpdateRequirementComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**requirement.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Requirement } from './requirement';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequirementService {
  private baseURL = "http://localhost:2021/getallrequirements";
  private URL1 = "http://localhost:2021/addRequirement";
  private URL2 = "http://localhost:2021/updatereq";
  private URL3 = "http://localhost:2021/getreq{resId}";

  


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getRequirementList(): Observable<Requirement[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Requirement[]>(`${this.baseURL}`)
  }

  addRequirement(requirement: Requirement): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.URL1}`, requirement);
  }

  getRequirementByresId(resId: number): Observable<Requirement>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Requirement>(`${this.URL3}/${resId}`);
  }

  updateRequirement(resId: number, requirement: Requirement): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.put(`${this.URL2}/${resId}`, requirement);
  }
}
```

**requirement.ts**

```
export class Requirement {
    resId: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    type: string;
    price: number;
    empId: number;
    isAvailable: string;
    availableUpto: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check browser's or db's log for any errors on GET? Maybe something's wrong on there?

Try an async pipe directly in the template instead of subscribing in the component since you use Observables anyway:

**requirement-list.component.ts**

```
{
...
  // asign the observable directly to variable and use with async pipe in template
  requirements$ = this.requirementService.getRequirementList(); 

  constructor(private  requirementService:  RequirementService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // no separate function needed for async pipe call
  }

  updateRequirement(resId: number){
    this.router.navigate(['update-requirement', resId]);
  }
}
```

**requirement-list.component.html**

```
...
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let requirement of requirements$ | async">
    <td>{{ requirement.resId}}</td>
...
```